# Random number generation - code not working as it should

Tags: matlab, random

So I have to generate a random number (called 'p' here) between 0 and 90 whose frequency distribution is a cosine function (i.e I should have more numbers between 0 and 45 than numbers between 45 and 90).

I am working on matlab
The code is as follows -

```
flag = 1; 
while flag == 1 
    candidate = randi([0,90]);
    if rand < cosd( candidate )
        p = candidate;
        flag = 2;
    end
end
```

I am generating 20 such numbers but always I get most of the numbers towards the higher end (45-90).
From those 20 numbers, there is hardly 1-2 numbers < 45.

Is my code wrong?

EDIT: Okay, so I got the answer. I tried running the code separately as follows-

```
for i = 1:20
  flag = 1; 
  while flag == 1 
      candidate = randi([0,90]);
      if rand < cosd( candidate )
          p = candidate;
          flag = 2;
          disp(p);
      end
  end  
end
```

And I'm getting most of the values of p between 0 and 45. My original code had an external 'if' condition which was the reason for only accepting higher values of 'p'. I used a while loop and the number of iterations were much more than 20 to get 20 values of 'p'.

Here is my original code snippet -

```
while zz <=20 
        d = randi([0,359]);
        flag = 1;

        while flag == 1 
            c = randi([0,90]);
            x = rand(1);
            if x < cosd(c)
                p = c;
                flag = 2;
            end
        end



        if 'external condition' 
              strike(zz) = d;
              dip(zz) = p;
              slip(zz) = round(i);
              zz= zz+1;
        end

end
```

Comment: Please include the code that you are using to test this, i.e. how are you generating the 20 numbers

Comment: rand generates random numbers between 0-1.

Comment: @PrithviThakur Please edit the new code you added and take out all the parts not relevant to the question. ONLY leave in the part where you store the random number `p`, i.e. make a loop where you generate a *20*-by-*1* vector of `p` values and then check the distribution of those.

Comment: @Dan I edited the code. Maybe, my 2nd 'if statement' is causing the problem, as in that condition ensures that only higher numbers are compatible.

Comment: @PrithviThakur that `abs(shear/normal_component)` is still irrelevant to your question (although it is part of the problem, it's a different problem). You have `while zz <= 20` and only increment `zz` under certain conditions, this runs more than 20 times but only considers `p` values meeting certain external criteria. To evaluate the correctness of your first code block (which btw I suspect is also logically flawed) then you must write code that ***ONLY*** runs that code block `n` times and saves `n` different values of `p`, then you can investigate the distribution of `p`

Comment: @Dan okay thanks, I tried that, and my first code block works correctly independently, so probably the external condition is the problem.
Please tell me if the first part is logically flawed, that would be of great help.
If the external criteria is the only problem, then my question is solved.

Comment: @PrithviThakur Edit your question to add in that test and how you concluded that it worked (and take out the other stuff, it belongs in a new question) - or if you're certain it works then add it as your own answer

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get answer, read the last line. But if you want to know that why that answer is right, read the explanation.

Assume that you have a distinct distribution function like this:

```
f(0)=1;
f(1.5)=10;
f(4)=9;
```

So the cumulative function is:

```
F(0)=1;
F(1.5)=11;
F(4)=20;
```

No we want to have a relative cumulative function, as `F(4)=20` (4 is the last item), we divide cumulative function by 20. So it would be:

```
F'(0)=0.05
F'(1.5)=0.55
F'(4)=1.00
```

Now, we generate a random number between 0 and 1. Every time we generate a random number, we generate a value for `F'(x)` and if `F'(x)` does not have that value anywhere, we use nearest bigger number (like y) which for some x, `F(x)=y`. For my example, based on relative cumulative function:

- If the random number was less than 0.05, our distribution-based random number is 1.5
- If the random number was between 0.05 and 0.55, our distribution-based random number is 2,
- If  was more than 0.55, our distribution-based random number is 4

We should do a similar work with continuous distribution functions. The difference is that in continuous world, we use integral instead of cumulative function. So for your question, we have:

```
f(x)=cos(x) , 0<=x<=90
F(x)=sin(x)-sin(0)=sin(x) , 0<=x<=90
F'(x)=cos(x) , 0<=x<=90   (Because F(90)=1)
```

Now we generate a random number between 0 and 1 (like `r`). So we have:

```
F'(x)=r => sin(x)=r => x=arcsin(r)
```

Actually, you just need to generate a random number between 0 and 1 and calculate the arcsin of that.

Comment: I didn't use Matlab too much. but in theory, you should do this.

Comment: @Dan: I edited it. Know it contains the whole theory.